# Concatenating variable and string batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

What is wrong with my below code? I am trying to write a batch file to publish a Database project. If I hard code the patch and file locations it works fine. But some how I am not able to get this working.
The error I get is

```
*** Argument 'SourceFile' has an invalid value: ''.
*** Argument 'Profile' has an invalid value: ''.
```

I have the following code currently.

```
SET SourceCodePath = "C:\SourceCode\Dev\Code"
SET DACPACPath = %SourceCodePath%\Source\Data Service\SQL2014\bin\Debug\SQL2014.dacpac
SET ProfilePath = %SourceCodePath%\Data Service\SQL2014\SQL2014.Local.publish.xml
ECHO %ProfilePath%
ECHO %DACPACPath%
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\dac\bin\SqlPackage.exe" /Action:Publish /SourceFile:%DACPACPath% /Profile:%ProfilePath%
PAUSE
```

Comment: Your question doesn't say what you mean by "get this working", but one obvious problem is that %ProfilePath% contains a space, and you haven't quoted it.

Comment: @Joe: Yes Sorry for that. Have updated the question now.

Comment: have you tried quoting the paths: /SourceFile:"%DACPACPath%" /Profile:"%ProfilePath%"

Comment: @Joe: Yes. I have tried that also but I get same error. Should be something silly but not able to figure out.

Comment: Try prefixing the last line with "ECHO ".  This will echo the command that's failing instead of executing it.  You can then try running it manually until you work out what's wrong.

Comment: @Joe: I am currently hardcoding the full path in the command instead of using variables. So it doesnt block me anyway. But wanted to write it in generic way so that others also can use it easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the command

```
SET SourceCodePath = "C:\SourceCode\Dev\Code"
```

creates a variable called  `SourceCodePath` with a blank character at the end

so, change your SET commands to

```
SET SourceCodePath=C:\SourceCode\Dev\Code
SET DACPACPath=%SourceCodePath%\Source\Data Service\SQL2014\bin\Debug\SQL2014.dacpac
....
```

Comment: I tried based on your suggestion but still I am getting the same output.